# How to convert NSArray to Set?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, set

Most of the posts here are on about how to convert a set into an array.But I would like to know if I could convert an array to a set.I have downloaded my array from parse and want to convert it to a set because I want the user to edit their details and the form builder I used needs to accept a set data type only.
This is what I got.The "Subjects" field is an NSArray in Parse.

```
let subjects = Set(currentuser?.objectForKey("Subjects"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the syntax is correct, but the compiler (and me too) doesn't know that the object for key `Subjects` is supposed to be an array. Use optional binding to check at least for an array of `NSObject` to conform to the requirement that the items in the array are hashable (thanks to dan for pointing that out):

```
if let userSubjects = currentuser?.objectForKey("Subjects") as? [NSObject] {
    let subjects = Set(userSubjects)
}
```

If the real type of `Subjects` is more specific than `[NSObject]` use that instead

Comment: You can't create a set from an `[AnyObject]` since `AnyObject` isn't `Hashable`.  You could probably use `[NSObject]` in this case since it is coming from an `NSArray`

Comment: Great! the real type of Subjects is [String] so should I edit the answer or leave it as it is so that other users can change it to suit their needs?

Comment: Please leave it as it is.